# regular expression that accepts numbers like 1,000.10?

Tags: regex

I have a problem with a regular expression. I would like an expression that accepts numbers like this :1.000,50
the dot indicates the thousands instead of the comma the decimal separator. In addition, I would like you to accept only two digits after the decimal point.
Can you help me? I've done this, but that's not what I want.

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```